# Create variables with a For each loop - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following

```
var invest401_2 = $("input[type=hidden][name=invest401_2]").val();  
var invest401_3 = $("input[type=hidden][name=invest401_3]").val();  
var invest401_4 = $("input[type=hidden][name=invest401_4]").val();  
var invest401_5 = $("input[type=hidden][name=invest401_5]").val();  

var invest401_0label = Math.round(((invest401_0/balance401)* percent401kb));    
var invest401_1label = Math.round(((invest401_1/balance401)* percent401kb));    
var invest401_2label = Math.round(((invest401_2/balance401)* percent401kb));    
var invest401_3label = Math.round(((invest401_3/balance401)* percent401kb));    
var invest401_4label = Math.round(((invest401_4/balance401)* percent401kb));
var invest401_5label = Math.round(((invest401_5/balance401)* percent401kb));

$("#invest401_0").text(invest401_0label+'%');
$("#invest401_1").text(invest401_1label+'%');
$("#invest401_2").text(invest401_2label+'%');
$("#invest401_3").text(invest401_3label+'%');
$("#invest401_4").text(invest401_4label+'%');
$("#invest401_5").text(invest401_5label+'%');
```

Having the count total -  ex. 5

How do a throw this into a for each loop.

I tried but didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `$.each`.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

If you add a class to this elements `$("input[type=hidden][name=invest401_2]").val();` you can get them as an array and use `each`.

If you add a class named `elements`. Use the following example.

```
$('.elements').each(function(i, element) {
    var invest = $(element).val();
    $(element).val(Math.round((invest/balance401)* percent401kb));
});
```

Or

```
var $elements = $('.elements');
for(var i in $elements) {
    var element = $elements[i];
    element.val(Math.round((element.val()/balance401)* percent401kb));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var invest401_label = [];
var invest401 = [];
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    invest401[i] = var invest401_2 = $("input[type=hidden][name=invest401_"+i+"]").val();
    invest401_label[i] = Math.round(((invest401[i]/balance401)* percent401kb));
    $("#invest401_"+i).text(invest401_label[i]+'%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only `#invest401_0 - 5`

```
$("[id=^invest401_]").each(function(){
    $(this).text(Math.round((($("input[type=hidden][name="+this.id+"]").val()/balance401)* percent401kb))+'%');
});
```

Reference

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not work ( I'm currently writing this from an ie8 machine) this /should/ do what you want correctly and replaces all of the code you have there

```
for (i = 0; i < $('.hiddenelems').size(); i++) {
    $('.hiddenelems:eq('+i+')').text(Math.round((($('.hiddenelems:eq('+i+')').val()/balance401)* percent401kb))+'%');
}
```